# Import error - Linkedin API

Tags: python, linkedin-api

When I'm trying to execute this code,

```
from linkedin import linkedin
from oauthlib import *

authentication = linkedin.LinkedInDeveloperAuthentication(CONSUMER_KEY,
                                 CONSUMER_SECRET, 
                                 USER_TOKEN, USER_SECRET, 
                                 RETURN_URL, 
                                 linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values())

# Pass it in to the app...

application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(authentication)

# Use the app....

g = application.get_profile()
print g
```

I get this error.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-ec5bf07a1f1d> in <module>()
  6 RETURN_URL = 'http://localhost:8000'
  7 
----> 8 from linkedin import linkedin
  9 from oauthlib import *
 10 

ImportError: cannot import name linkedin
```

But I have installed all these libraries -

```
linkedin,python-linkedin,requests,oauthlib
```

Why am I getting this error even though I have all the libraries installed?

Answer (score 2):

You have a conflict with your two linkedin libraries. 
Both are called using your `import linkedin` statement.

In order for it to work, you should uninstall the linkedin one, the LinkedInDeveloperAuthentication object being in the python-linkedin one using pip.

```
pip uninstall linkedin
```